# Add a tag filter to the "merge tags" dialog

Tags: feature-request, tags, moderator-tools

Specifically, I'd like to have the capability of doing something like this (pseudocode):

```
Merge [tag:activity] into [tag:android-activity] where post contains [tag:android]
Merge [tag:activity] into [tag:workflow-activity] where post contains [tag:WPF]
```

This new feature would allow me to selectively merge variants of the ambiguous tag into their non-ambiguous equivalents.

Note that, without this feature, the only way to disambiguate in my example is to search for [android](/questions/tagged/android) [activity](/questions/tagged/activity), and edit each post individually.

Comment: In these cases (or even generally) the retaggings should also be visible in the history of the individual posts (but without bumping them all).

Comment: Seconded. Would help with [tag:clustering] also. Merge [tag:clustering] into [tag:cluster-analysis] where post has tag [tag:k-means], for example. While [tag:JBoss] is an indicator for a very different kind of clustering.