# Disambiguating the "clustering", and "cluster" tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

[clustering](/questions/tagged/clustering) and [cluster](/questions/tagged/cluster) on Stack Overflow are quite ambiguous.
I'll cite computer-related terms from the Wikipedia disambiguation page for [Clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering).

- A result of cluster analysis. **1**
- An algorithm for cluster analysis, a method for statistical data analysis. **1**
- Cluster (computing), the technique of linking a many computers together to act like a single computer. **2**
- Data cluster, an allocation of contiguous storage in databases and file systems. **3**
- In hash tables, the mapping of keys to nearby slots. **3**
- The formation of clusters of linked nodes in a network, measured by the clustering coefficient. **1**

There seem to be three popular meanings: various types related to **cluster analysis** (**1**), **cluster-computing** (**2**) and **data storage/databases** (**3**).

There are a number of related tags on Stack Overflow:

- [clustering](/questions/tagged/clustering) 681 (**?** probably mostly Type **1**)
- [cluster](/questions/tagged/cluster) 475 (**?** probably mostly Type **2**)
- [cluster-computing](/questions/tagged/cluster-computing) 120 (Type **2**)
- [dataclustering](/questions/tagged/dataclustering) 42 (Type **1**)
- [clustered-index](/questions/tagged/clustered-index) 132 (Type **3**)
- [clustered](/questions/tagged/clustered) 18 (Type **3**?)
- [clusters](/questions/tagged/clusters) 16 (**?** probably mostly Type **2**)
- [database-cluster](/questions/tagged/database-cluster) 7 (Mixture of types **2** and **3**?)

In my opinion these tags would be more useful on SO if we did actually *not* have "cluster" and "clustering" tags (which are inherently used for both), but typing "cluster" will instead bring up the suggestions [cluster-analysis] and [cluster-computing]. In particular, when the questions are mostly using these tags, they should show up in the beginning of the list.

What do you think?

Comment: 1. Tag wikis where there are none. 2. Improve existing tag wikis. 3. What you wrote, +1.

Comment: I hadn't realised that you had brought this up on meta. Some of your retags are definitely not correct. You seem to have misfiled some type 3 ones. For example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936874/physically-cluster-a-mysql-table-for-better-performance) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590440/what-will-be-the-most-efficient-indexes-and-constraints-to-use-on-my-sql-server) have nothing to do with clustered computing. I'm not sure that database clustering is that relevant to the tag either but may be wrong on that.

Comment: Good point, database clustering is the more appropriate tag there I guess. In particular, when you read "clustered computing" as "distributed number crunching", then it doesn't really contain "database server clustering".

Comment: @Anony-Mousse - Yes that's more what I would associate the term with.

Comment: See also this feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119103, which should help with these kinds of disambiguations.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes. For example, "k-means" is a clear indication for "Type 1". While JBoss and Glassfish indicate a different meaning of "clustering".

Answer (score 3):

[dataclustering](/questions/tagged/dataclustering) already has a tag wiki describing it as [cluster-analysis](/questions/tagged/cluster-analysis), so we should probably merge [dataclustering](/questions/tagged/dataclustering) into [cluster-analysis](/questions/tagged/cluster-analysis)

Now that we have a [cluster-analysis](/questions/tagged/cluster-analysis) tag, we can make [clustering](/questions/tagged/clustering) and [data-clustering](/questions/tagged/data-clustering) synonyms of [cluster-analysis](/questions/tagged/cluster-analysis).

We can make [cluster](/questions/tagged/cluster) and [clusters](/questions/tagged/clusters) synonyms of [cluster-computing](/questions/tagged/cluster-computing)

And we can make [clustered](/questions/tagged/clustered) a synonym of [clustered-index](/questions/tagged/clustered-index)

And, of course, fixup all the tag wikis.

Comment: We should spend some thoughts on the exact names. As Martin brought up in the comments on the question, "cluster-computing" might to many not include the clustering of servers (database, web, failover, load-balancing), but true multi-core-computations. The better names we choose, the more likely users are to tag the questions right.

Comment: Perhaps add a [server-clustering] tag, with [clustered-server] and [database-cluster] synonyms?  [dataclustering] needs to be fixed anyway; it's too close to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cluster).  I think [cluster-computing] is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(computing)). [database-cluster] could potentially stand on its own.

Comment: I agree on dataclustering. The term "cluster-analysis" is much better. For this kind of "cluster-computing", tags such as "grid computing" or "supercomputing" might actually be more useful. But I figure it is okay. [server-clustering] sounds good to me, very clear. I'd keep database-cluster as an additional tag.