# Synonymize [limit], [limits] and [limitations]

Tags: support, synonym-request

Please make [limits](/questions/tagged/limits) and [limitations](/questions/tagged/limitations) synonyms of the [limit](/questions/tagged/limit) tag. They are used for the same thing, and the fact that [limits](/questions/tagged/limits) and [limitations](/questions/tagged/limitations) has no tag wiki makes things even more confusing.

Comment: I think some re-tagging might be in order rather than just squashing them all together. For example, I see a lot of `[limits]` questions are about the standard header files `limits.h` and `<limits>` in C and C++, while a lot of `[limit]` questions are about the LIMIT keyword in MySQL.

Comment: Hmm in that case tag wiki is even more important.

Comment: limits.h can be solved with a `[limits.h]` tag. The limit keyword in MySQL can be solved with a `[limit-mysql]` tag.  The retagging could be made much easier if we had [this feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119103)

Comment: PostgreSQL also has LIMIT keyword so maybe it should be sql-limit?

Comment: I didn't know that. Sure, of course. To aid in discoverability, there should be a `[limit-sql]` synonym.

Comment: [tag:limits.h] should probably synonymize [tag:climits]

Comment: we really need to set limitations on the limit of the amount of tags that have to do with limits