# Is there any way to perform a conditional merge?

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

While I've been adding tag wiki content to Android-specific tags, I've also been doing research on which tags are being used. In one such example [android-menu](/questions/tagged/android-menu), there are 509 questions with [menu](/questions/tagged/menu) and [android](/questions/tagged/android).

Obviously, in most cases, [android-menu](/questions/tagged/android-menu) would be the correct tag. Is there any way to merge [menu](/questions/tagged/menu) with [android-menu](/questions/tagged/android-menu) only if it includes the [android](/questions/tagged/android)? Fixing the tags after the merge would be far easier than editing them all manually. Not that I'm saying I'm not willing, but... meh.

Comment: Nope, sorry.  Although I've requested essentially that feature [here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119103/102937)